# How can I improve my script to make it faster when search from multiple sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

So this is my searching code in App script. I used it on My google sheet but sometimes it have to wait so long before I have the result from the script. I'm not sure how to make it faster.

```
function search_all(){
  const all = ["Sheet1","Sheet2"];
  const wsSheetForm = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SheetForm');

  for(var i in all){
  const wsPO = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID").getSheetByName(all[i]);
  const searchCell = wsSheetForm.getRange("H23").getDisplayValue();
  const values = wsPO.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
 
   for(var n=0; n<values.length; n++){
      var rowValue = values[n];

      if(rowValue[1] === searchCell && rowValue[5] === '1' && rowValue[25] == "0.00"){
        wsSheetForm.getRange("H22").setValue("N")
        wsSheetForm.getRange("C4").setValue(rowValue[10])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("H24").setValue(rowValue[2])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("C27:E27").setValue(rowValue[3])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("C28").setValue(rowValue[4])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("H27").setValue(rowValue[11])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("J27").setValue(rowValue[13])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("J28").setValue(rowValue[14])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("J74").setValue(rowValue[23])
        return;}

      if(rowValue[1] === searchCell && rowValue[5] === '1' && rowValue[25] != "0.00"){
        wsSheetForm.getRange("H22").setValue("V")
        wsSheetForm.getRange("C4").setValue(rowValue[10])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("H24").setValue(rowValue[2])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("C27:E27").setValue(rowValue[3])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("C28").setValue(rowValue[4])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("H27").setValue(rowValue[11])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("J27").setValue(rowValue[13])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("J28").setValue(rowValue[14])
        wsSheetForm.getRange("J74").setValue(rowValue[23])
        return;}
    }}};
```

I try to find the way to make it faster but not sure how gonna do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show seems fine. Chances are that the bad performance you mention is caused by the *spreadsheet* rather than the script. To improve spreadsheet performance, see [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).

You can make the code a bit better structured this way:

```js
function search_all() {
  const sheetRegex = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2)$/i;
  const formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SheetForm');
  const searchFor = formSheet.getRange('H23').getDisplayValue();
  const processRow = (row) => {
    if (row[1] !== searchFor || row[5] !== '1') {
      return false;
    }
    copyRowToForm_(row, formSheet);
    return true;
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
    .filter(sheet => sheet.getName().match(sheetRegex))
    .some(sheet =>
      sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().some(processRow)
    );
}

function copyRowToForm_(row, formSheet) {
  formSheet.getRange('H22').setValue(row[25] === '0.00' ? 'N' : 'V');
  formSheet.getRange('C4').setValue(rowValue[10]);
  formSheet.getRange('H24').setValue(rowValue[2]);
  formSheet.getRange('C27:E27').setValue(rowValue[3]);
  formSheet.getRange('C28').setValue(rowValue[4]);
  formSheet.getRange('H27').setValue(rowValue[11]);
  formSheet.getRange('J27').setValue(rowValue[13]);
  formSheet.getRange('J28').setValue(rowValue[14]);
  formSheet.getRange('J74').setValue(rowValue[23]);
}
```